# Android, convert call stream to text possible?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have a simple application that needs to call a number and speech-to-text (as best as possible) whatever the other party is saying.

Simply put, if the other party says "Hello", then "Hello" would be displayed on the screen.

I can make a call using `Intent.ACTION_CALL`:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:91234567"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

However, how do I continue from there, to convert the received audio signals to text?

Comment: Ask NSA. Surely they know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android, you cannot access or modify the call audio stream. Due to this, you cannot get what is being spoken, and hence cannot convert it to text.

This app isn't possible on Android.

Comment: Is there a way with android native dev kit, or  at least *some* other solution?

Comment: @Pacerier Its only possible if you're willing to build and customize android from source on a per device basis.

Comment: just wondering.. do you know if this app is possible on iPhone?

Comment: @Pacerier I'm not really an iOS dev, so I'm not sure but I don't think so.